# How to get label's text and pass it to a variable?

Tags: c#, watin

I would like to get a label value and pass it to a variable. Let's say I have:

```
<td class="label">
<label for="id5">**Text value**</label>
```

How can I pass string "Text value" to a variable? I tried:

```
string a = ie.Label(Find.ByFor("id5")).ToString();
```

but it doesn't get any value...

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Provide more details please.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Text-property (Gets the innertext of the element and the innertext of all the elements contained in the element.):

```
string a = ie.Label(Find.ByFor("id5")).Text;
```